# How do I solve this integral? Comes from Lyapunov equation and the derivative being negative definite

Tags: definite-integrals, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am sure this is a simple solution, but I just cant seem to get this solution

In sliding mode, following along with this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9WxwM6Ebvo&list=PLv8cjLiRoYbivwv0-wZOrHTS6pbydqDOe&index=1 , the lyapunov equation $\dot V \leq -\alpha V^{1/2}$ is integrated from $0$ to $t$ and the result is somehow $V^{1/2}(t) \leq -\frac{1}{2}\alpha t + V^{1/2}(0)$

I cannot seem to get this answer, can anyone help me out? How did they get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), namely the differential equation can be written as

$$
\frac{dV}{\sqrt{V}} \leq -\alpha\,dt.
$$

Comment: Wow I knew it was something simple I was just not seeing. Thank you!